# App failed to launch on Xcode after build successfully

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to launch the application on a real device from Xcode, but after building correctly the app doesn't launch.

The error is the following:

> Unable to launch bundle.identifier Domain: com.apple.platform.iphoneos
> Code: -12
> -- Request to launch "bundle.identifier" failed. Domain: com.apple.dt.deviceprocesscontrolservice Code: 2 Failure Reason: The
> operation couldn’t be completed. Application info provider
> (FBSApplicationLibrary) returned nil for "bundle.identifier" : Failed
> to launch process with bundle identifier 'bundle.identifier'.
> -- The operation couldn’t be completed. Application info provider (FBSApplicationLibrary) returned nil for "bundle.identifier" Domain:
> FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain Code: 4 Failure Reason: Application info
> provider (FBSApplicationLibrary) returned nil for "bundle.identifier"
> User Info: {
> BSErrorCodeDescription = NotFound; }

It started giving me this error when i changed bundle identifier to the application. I also tried to change the bundle identifier directly from info.plist and not only from project > Targets but the error persists.

Comment: It's referring to the bundle identifier for a library, not your app itself. Check the BBSApplication library. Delete and re-install for example.